# An elevator starts from rest. It’s acceleration is plotted against time. When it comes to rest it’s height above the starting point is

Tags: kinematics

[image]

Now velocity can be found by calculating the area under the slope. But that turns out to be 0, which is weird. It’s probably because I haven’t understood reading the graphs yet. It’s a simple question, but I still need help solving it.

$$Area=8-8=0$$
Which is obviously wrong. How should I do this?

Comment: No, that's not weird.  The fact that the area under the graph is 0 means that the **final** velocity is 0.  And you are **told** that it "has come to rest".

Comment: Draw velocity and time graph , area will give you height

Comment: @user247327 yeah I thought so, but this was driving me crazy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The elevator accelerates from rest at $2$ m/s$^2$ for $4$ seconds so it will reach a velocity of $2\cdot4 = 8$ m/s. It then continues at $8$ m/s for $4$ seconds, then decelerates at $-2$ m/s$^2$ for $4$ seconds back to zero velocity.

To get the distance traveled (height), as the acceleration is uniform, it's the average velocity of each segment times the time. This will be $4\cdot 4 + 8\cdot 4 + 4\cdot 4 = 64$ m.

Answer (score 0):

Draw velocity and time graph , area will give you height. it will be v=2t ,v=8 , v=-2t respectively for  your intervals it's a trapezoid of height 8 . you can take it from here

Comment: Is it possible to do it without drawing a graph?

Comment: @Aditya Sure, you can also calculate the integral $\int_{t=0}^{12}v(t)\,dt.$ Or make intellligent reasoning about the average speeds in the three intervals. I would think drawing the graph is easier.

Comment: It is easy with graph , Use $s=ut+\frac{1}{2}at^2$ if you want or do it by integral way